# Angular NgRx selector cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

So i need help, trying to figure out my school project example about using NgRx with api services.

I'm getting error in ngrx selector createSelector(), cannot read property of undefined.

Here is StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/github/NikolaLukic1/ngrx-example

I guess i messed up something with reducers, or in app.module.ts

Comment: Usually you need to have AppState. which I didn't find it in your code, if you configure that correctly it will set all states in initial state, and your issue will resolve, also I see you configure reducers twice in your app.module

Comment: I get that and i found some articles, but just couldn't make it work. 
I have only one state so i thought i can use it as such. 
Action is called and when i console action payload, i get my result, however i cannot set my posts variable with selector this way, like its not changing state...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector was not good. Firstly you have to check whether that state has property called 'posts' and then ask for it, it is a common issue these days.

Here you can find your [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-y65fkc) updated and working.

The code you need is here:

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

const selectPosts = (state: any) => state.hasOwnProperty('posts') ? state.posts : '';

export const selectedPosts = createSelector(
  selectPosts,
  (state: any) => {
    return state.hasOwnProperty('posts') ? state.posts : '';
  }
);
```

Comment: Ok i get it, i know it was undefined so thats one down..
Now get state after init, where my service is called to get data from api. 
Now its empty..

Comment: Can you check out how can i get state after OnInit method, where i posts$ is updated?
It's in app.component.ts file

Comment: Please make another question, this one is answered.

Comment: Btw, it should update itself because you use observable, it listen for change.

Comment: why do we twice slice .posts ? first in selectPosts then in selectedPosts selector. Feels to me like going to state.posts.posts

Comment: Exactly, that is weird but true.

Answer (score 2):

I use the safe navigation operator in these scenarios.

```
export const selectIsVerified = createSelector(
    selectCurrentUser,
    user => user?.emailVerified
)
```

This way the property won't be read until it is available if indeed, it ever comes available.