# NGRX Selector ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')

Tags: angular, ngrx

I try to learn NGRX.

I used this tutorial video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkoI_VHtcTU&ab_channel=MonsterlessonsAcademy

But, despite seeing everything working fine in the Redux Console of Chrome
I get an error for every Observable used in the html.

My Test Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LetModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one.component.scss']
})
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {

  private store = inject(Store<AppStateInterface>);
  isLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.select(customerLoadingSelector);
  customer$: Observable<Customer | null> = this.store.select(customerSelector);
  error$: Observable<string | null> = this.store.select(errorSelector);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(getCustomer());
  }

}
```

the html

```
<p *ngrxLet="isLoading$ as loading">loading: {{loading}}</p>
<p *ngrxLet="error$ as error">error: {{error}}</p>
<p *ngrxLet="customer$ as customer">customer: {{customer}}</p>
```

the actions

```
export const getCustomer = createAction('[Customer] get Customer');
export const getCustomerSuccess = createAction('[Customer] get Customer success', props<{ customer: Customer; }>());
export const getCustomerFailure = createAction('[Customer] get Customer failure', props<{ error: string; }>());
```

the reducer

```
export const initialState: CustomerStateInterface = {
  isLoading: false,
  customer: null,
  error: null
};

export const customerReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getCustomer, (state) => ({ ...state, isLoading: true })),
  on(getCustomerSuccess, (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: false,
    customer: action.customer
  })),
  on(getCustomerFailure, (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: true,
    error: action.error
  }))
);
```

And the selector

```
export const selectCustomer = (state: AppStateInterface) => state.customer;

export const customerLoadingSelector = createSelector(selectCustomer, (state: CustomerStateInterface) => state.isLoading);
export const customerSelector = createSelector(selectCustomer, (state: CustomerStateInterface) => state.customer);
export const errorSelector = createSelector(selectCustomer, (state: CustomerStateInterface) => state.error);
```

I am using the standalone concept so I added the provide store to my main.ts

```
bootstrapApplication(
  AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
      provideRouter(routes),
      provideStore(),
      provideRouterStore(),
      provideStoreDevtools(
        {
          maxAge: 25,
          logOnly: environment.production,
          autoPause: true
        }
      ),
      importProvidersFrom(
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        })
      )
    ]
  }
).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

the State and effect are in the route

```
{
    path: 'test',
    providers: [
      provideState(customerFeatureKey, customerReducer),
      provideEffects(CustomerEffects)
    ],
    loadComponent: () => import('../pages/test/test.page').then(c => c.TestPage)
  }
```

The Store is up. I see the Data switching in the console but the html use throughs errors.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried working with hasOwnProperty
but that didn't help
[Angular NgRx selector cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058551/angular-ngrx-selector-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)
I removed all index.ts files to be sure it's not them.

Comment: Where are you actually trying to read the variable or field `x`?

Comment: @possum x isLoading, error and customer in the html. All 3 through that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

Turned out i had a typo in my customerFeatureKey.
The key need to be the exact same as the state value key
of the selector.

```
export const selectCustomer = (state: AppStateInterface) => state.customer;
```

but key was

```
export const customerFeatureKey = 'csutomer';
```

[Ngrx selector return error cannot read property (reading 'payload')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847111/ngrx-selector-return-error-cannot-read-property-reading-payload)